# iOS MapBox RMShape

Tags: ios, polyline, mapbox

I am new to using RMPolylines and RMShapes and i think i am executing this code correctly but nothing is showing up on the map:

```
RMMapBoxSource *tilesource = [[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:kMapID];

[mapView setTileSource:tilesource];

 NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.981595 longitude:151.072900],[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.981560 longitude:151.073544],[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.981560 longitude:151.073845],[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.981666 longitude:151.074016], nil];

RMAnnotation *annoation43 = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView coordinate:((CLLocation *)[locations objectAtIndex:0]).coordinate andTitle:@"Hola biatches!"];

annoation43.userInfo = locations;
[annoation43 setBoundingBoxFromLocations:locations];
[mapView addAnnotation:annoation43];

-(RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapViewer layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation 
{
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        return nil;

    RMShape *shape = [[RMShape alloc] initWithView:mapView];

    shape.lineColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    shape.lineWidth = 5.0;

    for (CLLocation *location in (NSArray *)annotation.userInfo)
        [shape addLineToCoordinate:location.coordinate];

    return shape;
    NSLog(@"It is working Dora!");
}
```

So i think i have done something wrong here but i cannot pick it - if any more code or information is needed just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it is fixed now and seems to be a simple issue but if you know a detailed WHY this happened I would love to hear it!

Added the following:

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

I thought i had already set the delegate but evidently not!

Comment: Yeah, you will need a delegate set to use the `-mapView:layerForAnnotation:` delegate method, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `NSLog()` isn't ever going to run because of the `return`, but that's minor.

I see you basically followed the [shape example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/drawing-shape/). I'm not sure what could be wrong. Dumb question, but is the shape onscreen? i.e. is your map view showing an area that's covered by this shape?

Comment: Haha yes i just noticed the log. 

Yup as far as i can tell the shape is onscreen as i have also tried changing the mapID to a MapBox example map ID and still nothing shows up. However if i "copy, paste code" the EXACT shape example, the example RMShape line shows. I will have a look through my code and try and post some more information that could be relevant.