# RMPolylineAnnotation appearance changing when panning on MapBox

Tags: ios, mapping, mapbox

I have added an RMPolylineAnnotation to my rmMapView as follows in xcode:

```
RMPolylineAnnotation *polylineAnnotation = [[RMPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:rmMapView points:aPoints];
[polylineAnnotation setLineWidth:5.0f];
[polylineAnnotation setLineColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[polylineAnnotation setTitle:@"route"];

[rmMapView addAnnotation:polylineAnnotation];
```

This is drawing successfully when I load up my map:

[image]

However, if I pan until the route is off the screen, then pan back again it redraws the line without the parameters I've set:

[image]

As you can see I've tried setting the name to 'route' so that I can identify it within `- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation` but the layer is never redrawn, the circles are though even though they are added in exactly the same way. Does anyone know how I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase you are looking for an answer to this I used to approach here:

[iOS MapBox RMShape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167971/ios-mapbox-rmshape)

Adding the object as an RMShape instead, stopped my drawing issues.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Unbelievable how many of these bugs there are in the SDK still after a year.